# Accumulate in python with cap

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list

```
nums=[1,2,4,6]
```

i want to accumulate this list with a cap limit of 5, i.e if the accumulation value exceeds multiples of 5 it should print the value of multiples of 5 and then that value

**expected output:**

```
1
3
5
7
10
13
```

The code written is as follows:

```
nums=[1,2,4,6]
from itertools import accumulate
a= accumulate(nums)

for i in a:
    print(i)
```

the output that is being printed now

```
1
3
7
13
```

how can i get the desired output

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a Pythonic approach using a generator expression :

```
In [12]: from itertools import accumulate, chain

In [13]: list(chain.from_iterable((i,) if i < 5
             else (next(j for j in range(i, 0, -1) if j%5 == 0), i)
                     for i in accumulate(nums)))
Out[13]: [1, 3, 5, 7, 10, 13]
```

The logic is that you loop over the accumulated result and then for numbers greater than 5 you find the first number before it (using a reverse range and `next` function) that is a multiple of 5. Then concatenating the result using `itertools.chain()`.

From an algorithmic perspective, instead of performing multiple loops over the list, one by accumulate and another once for finding the expected numbers, you can do this at one traverse as following:

```
In [18]: def myaccumulate(lst):
    ...:     total = 0
    ...:     for num in lst:
    ...:         total += num
    ...:         for i in range(total, num, -1):
    ...:             if i%5 == 0:
    ...:                 yield i
    ...:                 break
    ...:         yield total
    ...:
```

Demo:

```
In [19]: list(myaccumulate(nums))
Out[19]: [1, 3, 5, 7, 10, 13]
```

This approach is actually faster than the generator-based one:

```
In [20]: %timeit list(myaccumulate(nums))
2.65 µs ± 47.9 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

In [21]: %timeit list(chain.from_iterable((i,) if i < 5 else (next(j for j in range(i, 0, -1) if j%5 == 0), i) for i in accumulate(nums)))
4.12 µs ± 21.3 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

Comment: instead of the range I think you could also do `i - i%5`

Comment: @pault Indeed but that doesn't make much of a different. The generator expression is already obscure by itself ;).

Comment: Agreed not a huge difference in this case, but if they were looking for previous multiple of 10000, it might start to matter.

Comment: This is probably the best answer. But I just *wish* it could be written in parts.

Comment: @Kasramvd when i use float numbers this is not working as expected, is there a workaround for it i just changed the lists to [1.011,2.23,4.5,6.0007] and tried the same code

Comment: @Python_newbie `range()` doesn't work with floats. Instead, you can use `math.ceil`, `round`, `math.floor` or other casting function to convert it to an integer.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one manual way. Not efficient, but readable. Assumes you are dealing with positive numbers.

```
from itertools import accumulate

nums = [1,2,4,6]

acc = list(accumulate(nums))  # regular accumulation
add = [i for i in range(5, acc[-1], 5) if i not in acc]  # multiples of 5 missing

res = sorted(acc + add)  # combine results and sort

print(res)

[1, 3, 5, 7, 10, 13]
```

---

An alternative way is possible using `set`:

```
add = list(set(range(5, acc[-1], 5)) - set(acc))
```

Comment: The `range(5, acc[-1], 5)` relies on the fact, that the largest element in `acc` is the last. But this is does not have to be true if the original list `nums` contains negative numbers...

Comment: @lkriener, Good point, fixable - but for now I'll just add disclaimer.